Plot marks exceed round margins / look strange
Using this code:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H] % cloud points POX
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=0.4\textwidth,
                xlabel={test},
                ylabel={plot},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend cell align={left},
                ]
                \addplot[color=CornflowerBlue, mark=*, dashed,line width=0.8pt]
                coordinates {(1,4.84)(2.5,4.61)(5,4.13)(10,4.45)(15,3.82)(20,3.31)(25,3.21)};
                \addlegendentry{A};
        
                \addplot[color=CornflowerBlue, mark=o, mark options={solid,fill=white}, dashed,line width=0.8pt]
                coordinates {(1,15.34)(2.5,14.69)(5,13.47)(10,13.95)(15,12.92)(20,12.08)(25,11.64)};
                \addlegendentry{B};                 
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I get marks that look strange:

But only for the filled marks in combination with a dashed line. Also the legend entry looks that way.
How can I fix this?

Strangeness confirmed. Note you should not have ; after \addlegend{}, else you get Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont! in the log.

Zooming in a lot, it seems the dash also applies to the circle, and thus not drawing the line al the way around. So they are circles if you remove dashed

It works when I add "mark options={solid}":
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H] % cloud points POX
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=0.4\textwidth,
                xlabel={test},
                ylabel={plot},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend cell align={left},
                ]
                \addplot[color=CornflowerBlue, mark=*, mark options={solid}, dashed, line width=0.8pt]
                coordinates {(1,4.84)(2.5,4.61)(5,4.13)(10,4.45)(15,3.82)(20,3.31)(25,3.21)};
                \addlegendentry{A}
        
                \addplot[color=CornflowerBlue, mark=*, mark options={solid,fill=white}, dashed, line width=0.8pt]
                coordinates {(1,15.34)(2.5,14.69)(5,13.47)(10,13.95)(15,12.92)(20,12.08)(25,11.64)};
                \addlegendentry{B}              
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

result:

